# "Am I a must when you are bored?" Does this sound natural?

Tags: word-usage

> Never assume that someone likes you by their sweetness. Sometimes you are just an option when they are bored.

That sentence comes from a native English speaker. So I was wondering if it's natural to say to someone "Am I an option when you are bored?" and if it's natural to say "Am I a must when you are bored?" Can that person understand me?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: How about "Am I an option when you are bored"?

Comment: Never assume that someone likes you by their sweetness.
Sometimes you are just an option when they are bored.

Comment: You need to ask more than a yes/no question to get more than a yes/no answer.

Comment: There are several different ways you could phrase something like that, all with slightly different meanings. I thought of, "Are you only my friend when you're bored?"

Comment: God, I thought of alcohol, a beer or cocktail speaking: "Am I a must when you are bored?" Yes!

Comment: Thanks for expanding on your question. I would say that "must" implies necessity which you perhaps might not intend. I offer "Why do you only come to me when you are bored?" as an option.

Comment: nice offer, accepted.

Comment: In fact, the feeling I want to express is that the person would not simply answer yes or no. Instead, I want him to reply "No, you are the must when I'm happy. I'd like to share good moments with only you.", which would be very romantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **must** is not an "option" or a "choice" or something to keep yourself occupied in a dull moment; rather it is a necessity, an imperative, or something that Prudence dictates.

> Closing the corral gate is a must if you wish to keep the cattle in
>   the pen. Don't forget to do it.
>
> Flossing regularly is a must if you wish to have your teeth all your
>   life.
>
> Passing this exam is a must if you wish to apply to graduate school.
>
> Some people regard popcorn as a must when they go to the movies.